# MacOS - Python 3.7 - GUI mouse control for DirectX 8 (2003) app - unable to simulate mouse clicks but I can simulate keyboard entry

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to control an old DirectX application from a Python script. The application concerned is from 2003 (ish). Launches full screen (in a Desktop space) in OSX and requires the mouse be 'freed' via a command. Once the mouse is freed you can use it normally.

I have tried scripting to simulate a mouse click. I have used AppleScript and Python to no avail.
Keyboard simulation does work. For example the first thing any scripting does is swap into the relevant desktop space with a shortcut then hit a keyboard shortcut in the app. This works.
Moving the mouse around the app with scripting works.

However the following will not work.
1) Simulated clicks from code.
2) Turning on mouse keys and simulating a keyboard click in code. Note if I turn on mouse keys and manually hit the mouse click key in the app this does work.

Doesn't work -

```py
import pyautogui
pyyautogui.click()

from pynput import Button,Controller
mouse = Controller()
mouse.click(Button.left, 2)
```

So basically simulating the keyboard works in the app but I am struggling to simulate a mouse click (moving the mouse works fine). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

are you saying you want to write with pyautogui? you can use this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.write('An example')
```